Dark Gray/Black is poor choice for colour on visited links
It appears that Stack Overflow have pushed another change to the themes to the site (probably (confirmed to be) in the name of "accessibility"), however, it appears that on meta the chosen colour for links to user profiles that you have visited it black, the same colour as normal text. This makes it appear as it user names are no longer clickable; this, in my opinion, is the complete opposite to "accessible". Please, Stack Overflow, choose a different colour or (possibly better), just don't have a different colour for hyperlinks for profile's you've viewed before. *I can't remember what it was like before this change).
You can see in the below screenshot that My, Security Hound, Kevin B, and Gimby all have their names in a colour that is more or less the same colour as the comment's text, where A-Tech, Dharman, and others are red.

If I visit Dharman and A-Tech's profile's, and the linked question, I now see this:

The linked question isn't awful, as it is underlined, but profile names aren't, so just don't look interactable.
There may be other sites with similar issues, but it's not a problem across the board. For example, on DBA Meta and Stack Exchange Meta, visited links aren't black (nbk and Sebastian Simon are a visited links respectively), and it appears a different shade of the same colour for non-visited links is used:


More confusing, is that deleted users and visited user profile links appear to be the same colour, however, deleted users don't have an interactable name. You can now only tell a user is deleted (on meta) because they don't have a reputation value adjacent to their name:

As Dan Mašek comments for badges with a dark ground, the text colour for those links has also been chosen to be the same colour, making the text appear invisible.


Definitely a bug, it makes links appear completely un-discernable

Always happy to be a bug.

Possibly related - https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/402147

And visited badges now are black on black. Priceless.

Oh, that's "beautiful", @DanMašek . I'll add that to the post.

Related: Links should not look the same as plain text

The release was today, @Laurel ; that post is from 2022. It's about a similar issue, sure, but it's not a related problem.

Thanks for flagging. It looks like today's change caused the badges issues. As far as the link text is concerned, it was not part of today's release. The best we can say is that it may have been introduced about 10 months ago. But I am poking around to see if I can get someone to pick it up in the nearish future.

@SpencerG I can assure you that the links were not that colour this morning; this is something that has changed today. It might not have been intended to be part of today's changes, but it certainly was part of it.

@SpencerG the visited links weren't essentially unrecognisable as links for 10 months. Come on. And if they were, sounds like it should have been fixed 10 months ago.

@VLAZ ; when is a bug not a bug? When the bug should have been released 10 months ago but wasn't until today. Then it's [[meta-tag:status-bydesign]].

Wait, what? Do we now have release schedules for bugs?
